# Unable to establish connection with minikube cluster from host

Tags: curl, networking, kubernetes, minikube, virtual-network

I am following [this fission tutorial](https://github.com/fission/fission) on a remote bare metal instance. When I run curl $FISSION_URL (http://192.168.42.152:31313) it does not return. I ran the following commands:

1. sudo lsof -i | grep 192.168.42.152.

> ntpd       2860             ntp   32u  IPv4  55241      0t0  UDP 192.168.42.1:ntp
>
> dnsmasq    3392 libvirt-dnsmasq    5u  IPv4  33870      0t0  UDP 192.168.42.1:domain
>
> dnsmasq    3392 libvirt-dnsmasq    6u  IPv4  33871      0t0  TCP 192.168.42.1:domain (LISTEN)

2. curl -vvv $FISSION_URL.

> Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.42.152:31313/
>
> Trying 192.168.42.152...
>
> Connected to 192.168.42.152 (192.168.42.152) port 31313 (#0)
>
> GET / HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 192.168.42.152:31313
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
>
> Accept: */*

3. sudo iptables -L

   ```
   Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
   Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
   Chain DOCKER (1 references)
   target     prot opt source               destination         
   Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
   target     prot opt source               destination                 

   RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
   ```

I am unsure on how I should proceed with debugging this. I believe the host is able to connect with the guest (minikube IP) but unable to retrieve data. Can anyone guide me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you start the minikube instance and run the commands given in the [doc](https://github.com/fission/fission) that says

```
kubectl create -f http://fission.io/fission.yaml
kubectl create -f http://fission.io/fission-nodeport.yaml
```

Then run following to set the kubernetes context

```
kubectl config set-context minikube --namespace fission
```

Now to get the state of current deployment just run, please post output of following commands:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
kubectl get svc -o wide
kubectl get events
```

---

For me it is working:

```
$ export FISSION_URL=http://$(minikube ip):31313
$ curl $FISSION_URL
{"message": "Fission API", "version": "0.1.0"}
```

My state looks like this:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
controller-1637203237-g5lw1    1/1       Running   0          16m       172.17.0.6   minikube
etcd-2122244727-6vl4v          1/1       Running   0          16m       172.17.0.8   minikube
kubewatcher-2300228496-7kbw3   1/1       Running   1          16m       172.17.0.7   minikube
poolmgr-3531518326-nsxmr       1/1       Running   3          16m       172.17.0.5   minikube
router-2621354073-q1hw7        1/1       Running   3          16m       172.17.0.4   minikube
```

and

```
$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE       SELECTOR
controller   10.0.0.191   <nodes>       80:31313/TCP   15m       svc=controller
etcd         10.0.0.41    <none>        2379/TCP       16m       svc=etcd
poolmgr      10.0.0.252   <none>        80/TCP         16m       svc=poolmgr
router       10.0.0.108   <nodes>       80:31314/TCP   15m       svc=router
```

and events are [here](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/2h1RhvyjtwhYPubychnmfV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I run `kubectl get pods -o wide` I see that all my pods are in the `ContainerCreating` state. I checked `kubectl get events` and found this error: `Warning FailedSync Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0\"".` I found [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/322) link on a similar issue. Could you guide me on where I can set the `--docker-env flag` for proxies? I was unable to understand the fix. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can find the help with proxy in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/530#issuecomment-250801735)

Comment: Thanks! But when I run env | grep -i proxy it doesn't return anything. So I don't think that proxy is the reason for this. 
I noticed that when I run kubectl get endpoints, it shows me that no IP has been assigned to any of the pods. Is this normal? I was unable to find anything regarding this online.

Comment: If you show events from `kubectl get events` I can say if anything is wrong?

Comment: I have attached the output of `kubectl get events` in the question above. 
```LASTSEEN   FIRSTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                          KIND      SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON       SOURCE              MESSAGE
11s        16h         3448      controller-1637203237-8f6m4   Pod                   Warning   FailedSync   kubelet, minikube   Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0\""
```
That is repeated for every pod. I have attached the event log in the question above.

Comment: it seems that your minikube machine is not connected to internet please see that it is connected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did have an internet connectivity issue in my VM. Now it works as expected.